# Es correcto evitar los if´s?

Tags: c#, poo, revisión-de-código, herencia

Un programador conocido me sembró una gran duda diciéndome que el siguiente código se puede lograr de la misma manera sin la necesidad de `if` al llamar a la clase abstracta.

```
 abstract class Clases
{
    public abstract int[] Atributos();
}


class Guerrero : Clases
{
    public int _StatFuerza = 10;
    public int _StatDestreza = 10;
    public int _StatConstitucion = 10;
    public int _StatInteligencia = 10;
    public int _StatSabiduria = 10;
    public int _StatCarisma = 10;
    public int _StatHealthPower = 10;

    public override int[] Atributos()
    {
        int[] atr = new int[6];
        atr[0] = _StatFuerza;
        atr[1] = _StatDestreza;
        atr[2] = _StatConstitucion;
        atr[3] = _StatInteligencia;
        atr[4] = _StatSabiduria;
        atr[5] = _StatCarisma;
        atr[6] = _StatHealthPower;
        return atr;
    }
}

class Mago : Clases
{
    public int _StatFuerza = 15;
    public int _StatDestreza = 15;
    public int _StatConstitucion = 15;
    public int _StatInteligencia = 15;
    public int _StatSabiduria = 15;
    public int _StatCarisma = 15;
    public int _StatHealthPower = 15;

    public override int[] Atributos()
    {
        int[] atr = new int[6];
        atr[0] = _StatFuerza;
        atr[1] = _StatDestreza;
        atr[2] = _StatConstitucion;
        atr[3] = _StatInteligencia;
        atr[4] = _StatSabiduria;
        atr[5] = _StatCarisma;
        atr[6] = _StatHealthPower;
        return atr;
    }

}
```

Asi llamo a esa clase

```
     public void Estadisticas(int _mainEXP, string especializacionSelec, string razaSelec)
        {

            int bonusClassFuerza;
            int bonusClassDestreza;
            int bonusClassConstitucion;
            int bonusClassInteligencia;
            int bonusClassSabiduria;
            int bonusClassCarisma;
            int bonusClassHp;

            if (especializacionSelec == "Guerrero")
            {
                int[] especialidad = new Guerrero().Atributos();
                bonusClassFuerza = especialidad[0];
                bonusClassDestreza = especialidad[1];
                bonusClassConstitucion = especialidad[2];
                bonusClassInteligencia = especialidad[3];
                bonusClassSabiduria = especialidad[4];
                bonusClassCarisma = especialidad[5];
                bonusClassHp = especialidad[6];
            }
            else if (especializacionSelec == "Mago")
            {
                int[] especialidad = new Mago().Atributos();
                bonusClassFuerza = especialidad[0];
                bonusClassDestreza = especialidad[1];
                bonusClassConstitucion = especialidad[2];
                bonusClassInteligencia = especialidad[3];
                bonusClassSabiduria = especialidad[4];
                bonusClassCarisma = especialidad[5];
                bonusClassHp = especialidad[6];
            }
       }
```

¿Esta es la forma correcta de programar?.

¿Se puede simplificar aun mas el código? .

¿Hasta que punto se aplica la regla de no repetirse? .

¿El uso de ifs afecta el desarrollo correcto del código?.

Busque información relacionada con el tema y gracias a este ejemplo fue como aprendí a crear clases abstractas.

[Ejemplo Practico de las Clases Abstractas](http://www.mundoprogramacion.com/colabora/puntoNET/sergio_ClaseAbstracta.htm)

Comment: Yo creo que lo suyo sería desarrollar una interfaz para todo esto y que cada clase tuviera ciertos atributos por defecto, creando después objetos para cada una de las clases. Pero esta es mi opinón.

Comment: El uso del if ahí te puede afectar en la escabilidad de tu programa.
Si podés investiga el principio de sustitución de Liskov ahí creo que puede estar lo que buscas pero mejor aún si podes decile a tu programador conocido que te explique que te quiso decir.
Las otras preguntas son mas que nada opiñones, un saludo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
¿Esta es la forma correcta de programar?.
```

difícil definir que es lo correcto, para esto uno se tiene que basar en criterios de calidad de software para poder llegar a la mejor solución para tu problema. Lo que si uno podría decir que esta correcto usar clases abstractas para definir un tipo **base** de clase.

```
¿Se puede simplificar aun mas el código?
```

Siempre se puede simplificar más el código, para este caso podrías sobrecargar el método Estadísticas para generar una lógica para guerreros y magos.

```
¿Hasta que punto se aplica la regla de no repetirse? .
```

hay que tratar de aplicarla siempre, pero depende de la experiencia del programador en este caso para ver que exista un orden y legibilidad en el código.

```
¿El uso de ifs afecta el desarrollo correcto del código?.
```

Va a depender de quien programe. si se genera un método de cientos de lineas de código con multiples IF, hay un problema. lo importante es analizar si existe algún patron de diseño que me ayude a programar de manera más modular.

Si nos apegamos a los principios de programación orientada a objetos,  las líneas de código que incluyen IF para  verificar un valor de una propiedad de un objeto "rompen" el principio de encapsulación.

Si lo vemos como fuentes de errores, va a depender del programador tener el código bien implementando para que los ifs se cumplan y no se genere un error al preguntar por una propiedad de un objeto que no exista o se olvide que no es lo mismo "hola" que "Hola" para preguntar por una igualdad de strings y se omita un bloque de instrucciones por eso. Etc.

En cuanto a performance, los compiladores ven los If / Else como un salto a otro bloque de código. esta operación es muy estándar y bien optimizada para que se cumpla de manera fácil para cualquier procesador, así que en este ámbito es NO.

Answer (score 1):

**Advertencia: Es un poco confuso hablar de clases (guerrero, mago, etc.) y clases de C++, he intentado dejarlo claro marcándolo entre paréntesis. También hay veces que me refiero a los dos a la vez...**

El uso de la clase abstracta te permite tener el código separado. Cada clase (Mago, Guerrero, y las otras que haya) puede ir en un archivo separado, así puedes tener el código más ordenado.

Cuantas más funciones añadas (ahora solo nos has mostrado `Atributos` o `Estadisticas`, pero seguro que hay más o habrá más), más largo se te haría el archivo si lo hicieras con `if-else`. Imaginate que tienes 5 clases (guerrero, mago), cada clase necesita 10 funciones, cada función son al menos 15 líneas de código (y eso es poco). Son `5 * 10 * 15 = 750` líneas en un mismo archivo, y me parece poco que tenga 10 funciones y 15 líneas. Imagínate cómo escalará eso conforme necesites más y más funciones o clases (guerrero, mago), etc.

Además, te será más fácil equivocarte con los `if-else` en un mismo archivo que si tienes 5 archivos distintos (uno por clase (guerrero, mago)).

Por otro lado, al tener la clase abstracta, puedes ver de un vistazo las funciones esenciales de cada clase (guerrero, mago, etc), porque están definidas ahí.

Si además usas herencia, puedes definir también funciones que sean comunes a todas las clases, así también te evitas tener que repetir código que es igual para cada tipo de clase (guerrero, mago). Así también puedes definir sub-clases (Mago podría ser: hechicero, druida, mago oscuro, nigromante, etc., Guerrero podría ser: Arquero, soldado, mercenario, etc.).

Al final tienes un programa con muchos archivos, pero si los ordenas bien no hay problema, los archivos son más cortos y claros, cada uno se refiere a una cosa. Si cambias alguna característica del guerrero, solo tienes que abrir un archivo y todo lo que cambies afectará solo al guerrero, si tienes que buscar en los `if-else` tienes que andarte con ojo de no cambiar de otro.

> ¿Esta es la forma correcta de programar?.

No hay una norma de siempre hacerlo así. Es una buena idea para lo que tienes entre manos, pero en otros casos convendrá usar `if-else`. Lo que tienes que hacer, y es parte del trabajo del programador, es conocer las herramientas que te da el lenguaje de programación, conocer tus necesidades, y entonces hacer la mejor decisión que puedas respecto a qué usar. Siempre puedes dar un paso atrás y cambiarlo, pero tomar la mejor decisión posible desde el primer momento te evita tener que cambiarlo todo luego, porque perderás el tiempo haciendo cambios que a nivel de usuario no se notarán, en lugar de poder añadir mejoras al programa.

> ¿Se puede simplificar aun mas el código? .

No sabría decirte, dependerá de cómo es todo el código, por lo que nos has mostrado, parece bastante sencillo, pero seguro que es más complejo en el fondo. La idea de usar herencia puede ser útil, pero tendrás que ver si aplica o no a tu caso.

> ¿Hasta que punto se aplica la regla de no repetirse? .

Sencillamente, el sentido común te dirá. Si vas a perder legibilidad del código por no repetir, entonces quizá convenga repetir, ten en cuenta que probablemente no programes solo. Pero sí, siempre intenta no repetir código, es uno de los puntos en los que más énfasis me parece que se hace, y me parece correcto.

> ¿El uso de ifs afecta el desarrollo correcto del código?.

El `if` es una herramienta más que provee el lenguaje de programación, hay que usarla cuando tenga sentido, no hay más. La cosa es conocer las demás herramientas para saber cuando el `if` es lo mejor y cuándo tendrás que usar un `switch`, `for`, `while`, `do-while`, `clases`, `herencia`, etc.

Comment: Hola Arian, agradezco mucho el tiempo que te tomaste para explicarmelo todo. No se si varia en algo C++ y C# en cuanto a las repsuestas que me diste ya que me parecen mas generales a todos los lenguajes que exclusivos del c#, no entiendo el punto negativo que alguien te habrá dado. Ahora me queda mas en claro en cuanto a como funcionan las cosas en el ámbito POO, espero solventar rapidamente mi duda ya que estoy dando vueltas desde ayer con esto, nuevamente muchas gracias por el tiempo.

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya ayudado. Sí, la respuesta es más general, pero las preguntas que haces creo que también son generales y aplican a muchos lenguajes de programación (no todos). Ni me he enterado del negativo, pero lo suyo es que dejen un comentario explicando la razón y quizá se pueda corregir, o al menos hablar de ello.

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver el problema de los `if` se debe hacer lo siguiente.

Se crea la clase abstracta

```
    namespace WindowsFormsApp1.razas
{

    public abstract class Razasbase
    {
        public abstract string Nombrederaza { get; }
        public abstract int Fuerza { get; }
        public abstract int Destreza { get; }
        public abstract int Constitucion { get; }
        public abstract int Inteligencia { get; }
        public abstract int Sabiduria { get; }
        public abstract int Charisma { get; }
        public abstract int HealthPower { get; }
    }

    public class Humano : Razasbase
    {
        public override string Nombrederaza => "Humano";
        public override int Fuerza => 12;
        public override int Destreza => 8;
        public override int Constitucion => 9;
        public override int Inteligencia => 4;
        public override int Sabiduria => 7;
        public override int Charisma => 11;
        public override int HealthPower => 5;
    }
    public class Elfo : Razasbase
    {
        public override string Nombrederaza => "Elfo";
        public override int Fuerza => 12;
        public override int Destreza => 8;
        public override int Constitucion => 9;
        public override int Inteligencia => 4;
        public override int Sabiduria => 7;
        public override int Charisma => 11;
        public override int HealthPower => 5;
    }

    public class Orco : Razasbase
    {
        public override string Nombrederaza => "Enano";
        public override int Fuerza => 12;
        public override int Destreza => 8;
        public override int Constitucion => 9;
        public override int Inteligencia => 4;
        public override int Sabiduria => 7;
        public override int Charisma => 11;
        public override int HealthPower => 5;

    }

    public class Mediano : Razasbase
    {
        public override string Nombrederaza => "Mediano";
        public override int Fuerza => 12;
        public override int Destreza => 8;
        public override int Constitucion => 9;
        public override int Inteligencia => 4;
        public override int Sabiduria => 7;
        public override int Charisma => 11;
        public override int HealthPower => 5;

    }
}
```

Se llama a la clase de la siguiente manera

```
        List<razas.Razasbase> Razas = new List<razas.Razasbase>
    {
            new razas.Humano(),
            new razas.Orco(),
            new razas.Elfo(),
            new razas.Mediano(),
    };
```

aprovechando que lo pasamos como una lista podemos llenar un `datagridview` con esta nueva información

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("id");

            for (int i = 0; i < Razas.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                row["id"] = (string.Format("{0} - {1}", i, Razas.ElementAt(i).Nombrederaza));
                dt.Rows.Add(row);

            }
 DataView view;
 view = new DataView(dt);
 dataGridView1.DataSource = view;
```

Si queremos extraer la información al respecto de alguna de las `Razas` usamos alguno de los disparadores que nos ofrece el datagridview como por ejemplo de que al clickear la celda este dispare un determinado void, y aprovechando que ya clickeamos en una que nos traiga la referencia de en que posición de la tabla estamos para que pueda acceder al valor en concreto y de esta manera devolvernos los datos referentes a nuestro parametro de busqueda.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        List<razas.Razasbase> Razas = new List<razas.Razasbase>
        {
            new razas.Humano(),
            new razas.Orco(),
            new razas.Elfo(),
            new razas.Mediano(),
        };

        DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        int i = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;

        razas.Razasbase raza = Razas.ElementAt(i);

        string msg = string.Format("Raza: {0} \n Fuerza: {1} \n Destreza: {2} \n Constitucion: {3}" +
            "\n Inteligencia: {4} \n Sabiduria: {5} \n Carisma: {6} \n HP: {7} ", 
            raza.Nombrederaza, raza.Fuerza, raza.Destreza, raza.Constitucion, raza.Inteligencia, 
            raza.Sabiduria, raza.Charisma, raza.HealthPower);


        MessageBox.Show(msg);
    }
```

Captura del resultado final.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me auto-respondo porque es una manera personal de seguir creciendo y para que alguna otra persona que este en mi misma situación y se haya topado con esta publicación de casualidad tenga un poco mas de idea de como resolver algunos de sus problemas.